# How to check is today a working day (mon-fri)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm searching to method how to check is today a working day monday-friday. I'm using moment.js. I'm getting today date as `moment()`

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/  Did you search the docs at all?

Comment: @Taplar I cheked, this link don't help my question

Comment: "This method can be used to set the day of the week, with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6." How does that not help you determine that the day is a work day?  If you do not give it a value, it returns the current in number format, 0-6.  It should be fairly straight forward logic to determine if the number falls in the range of what numbers correspond to work days.

Comment: @Taplar well, I can compare moment() with moment.day(0) and moment.day(1), u think it is good solution?

Comment: Don't give `day()` a value.  That would *change* it.  Just call `day()` to get the current day's number

Comment: @Taplar ohhhh, I'm sorry, u are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use moment

```
const today = moment().format('dddd')
```

This will return the date string. 
If you want the today week number than :

```
const today = moment().day();
```

which returns a number between 0 - 6 
So day 6 and 0 are non working days.

I would wrap it in a function

```
  function isWorkDay(date = moment()){
      const day = moment(date).day())
      return day && day < 6 
}
```